# How to insert data into a database using C?

Tags: iphone, mysql, c, database

How do i insert data from an iPhone app to the mysql database using C? I have a web app that inserts into database but now looking into iphone.

Comment: We need more information on what you have tried and the environment on which you are trying to do this on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short - you need to have a server (the one with the MySQL database) which defines a layer of 'services' that the iOS application can call.  You could design this service layer in PHP, Python, NodeJS, etc.... It doesn't matter how you do it - but you need to have some service layer to handle the interactions.

Another (not recommended) approach would be to access MySQL directly using a driver written in Objective-C.  Here is one such driver:

http://www.karlkraft.com/index.php/2010/09/17/mysql-for-iphone-and-osx/